# Xcode 7 Playground execution EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift-playground, xcode7

Running the simplest, default code in Xcode 7 playgrounds... get the following error

`` Playground execution failed: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8).
* thread #1: tid = 0x351bc3, 0x00000001062019ca libicucore.A.dylib`utext_clone + 22, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
  * frame #0: 0x00000001062019ca libicucore.A.dylib`utext_clone + 22
    frame #1: 0x000000010633ac42 libicucore.A.dylib`icu::RegexMatcher::reset(UText*) + 54
    frame #2: 0x0000000106375414 libicucore.A.dylib`uregex_setText + 222
    frame #3: 0x0000000103d1b445 Foundation`-[NSRegularExpression(NSMatching) enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:] + 2325
    frame #4: 0x0000000103d65d7e Foundation... ``

Cannot run anything in playgrounds basically.

Running beta 4 (7A165t)

I also have Xcode 6.2 running playgrounds just fine on the same mac.

Answer (score 2):

Complete reinstall of all versions of Xcode plus deleting folder Library/Developer fixes the issues (see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13969).

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue - before a fresh install check you haven't got IOS simulator running in the background anywhere from another xcode project or previous session. Once I closed the IOS simulator, closed xcode and re-launched and opened the playground again it worked fine. Seems I had a problem with xcode trying to open multiple simulators.

Answer (score -1):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` Exception thrown when you try to send a message to already released object.
Apple provides mechanics with special class `NSZombie` which replace every released object in memory.

You could find more details on following links:

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/

http://loufranco.com/blog/understanding-exc_bad_access

Comment: Thanks for the details but this didn't answer the question.. which is why I get the error every time even with the simplest code.

Comment: This doesn't in any way address the original poster's problem which is Playgrounds are broken by default for many users of Xcode 7.